# Purpose and scope of AWS CDK bootstrap stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

The [docs](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cdk-bootstrap) on AWS CDK boostrapping state of the `cdk bootstrap` command:

```
cdk bootstrap
Deploys a CDKToolkit CloudFormation stack into the specified environment(s), that provides an S3 bucket that cdk deploy will use to store synthesized templates and the related assets, before triggering a CloudFormation stack update. The name of the deployed stack can be configured using the --toolkit-stack-name argument.

$ # Deploys to all environments
$ cdk bootstrap --app='node bin/main.js'

$ # Deploys only to environments foo and bar
$ cdk bootstrap --app='node bin/main.js' foo bar
```

However, how often does CDK need to be bootstrapped?  Is it:

- once for each AWS account?
- once for each application in each AWS account?
- once for each application in each AWS account that requires assets?
- something else?

Comment: I do not recommend to use single bootstrap for all cdk application in your account/region. Add different qualifiers, and bootstrap stack names for different cdk applciations.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

background:

> cdk bootstrap is a tool in the AWS CDK command-line interface
> responsible for populating a given environment (that is, a combination
> of AWS account and region) with resources required by the CDK to
> perform deployments into that environment.

When you run `cdk bootstrap` cdk deploys the CDK toolkit stack into an AWS environment.

The bootstrap command creates a CloudFormation stack in the environment passed on the command line. Currently, the only resource in that stack is An S3 bucket that holds the file assets and the resulting CloudFormation template to deploy.

cdk bootstrap command is running one time per account/ region.

**Simple scenario to sum-up:**

1. Run `cdk bootstrap` - create a new s3 bucket, IAM roles, etc.
2. Run `cdk deploy` - to deploy your stack for the first time, new template added to bootstrap s3 bucket.
3. Apply any change to cdk stack.
4. Run `cdk diff` - to view differences -

Behind the scenes, CDK generates the new template and compare it with the CDK template that exists in the bootstrap bucket.

More about [cdk bootstrap](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/design/cdk-bootstrap.md).

Comment: Hi Amit, could you explain why the bootstrap command tries to execute the application defined in the current folder. If the bootstrap command simply sets up to allow deployments, why does it also try to deploy an application?

Comment: @cbp What do you mean by `also try to deploy an application`? can you supply an example?

Comment: @Arun/@Amit, does it mean if i have existing stack on cloudformation already, would bootstrap wipe it off and create a clean slate? cdk deploy error points me to run bootstrap command but docs are not clear about if it would create other side effects. would appreciate any pointers, pls.

Comment: @Vijay as much as i can tell, no. cdk bootstrap is for new stacks only

Comment: Thanks, @Amit. confirmed, it didn't delete older stacks. however i get 403 error while trying to establish connection using wscat -c command and struggling to figure that out.